# Download link of "Google Contacts API version 3.0" for .NET

Tags: .net, google-contacts-api

I have 2.0 version of Contacts API.
But i am looking for newer version "Contacts API version 3.0" **for .NET** .

Can anyone send me download like for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Google Contacts Data API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html), you cannot download it because it does not exist.  As of today, that page lists the the latest .NET version as 2.0.