# where is a thorough, accurate and complete description of Google Contacts API 3.0?

Tags: google-contacts-api

Google Contacts API 3.0 is described here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference But this document is not complete.

In googles contacts form I can enter a name that is used to file the record rather than the contacts full name. I can access the record via XML or JSON and I get this field as `gContact:fileAs`. But the reference-Document does not contain a description of `gContact:fileAs`.

What else is missing in this reference-document?

On the other hand the description contains fields like gContact:billingInformation or gContact:jot or gContact:mileage that seem not to have a place in the contact form. So to me there seems to be no way to enter values into one of those fields, so they never will contain anything, and so they never will appear in the xml- or json-file that I can get from google. So I think there is no need to implement those fields in my application. - Or am I wrong with this?

### So, please:

Where is a thorough, accurate and ***complete*** description of Google Contacts API 3.0?

Comment: Probably nowhere, since you've listed the authoritative source for that API as being incomplete.

Comment: Google doesn't have the complete v3 API up yet:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528398/download-link-of-google-contacts-api-version-3-0-for-net

Comment: @AlexW: The question you linked to is two years old and deals with a .NET-implementation of this protocol.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Google for a better reference if the authoritative reference has errors?

Comment: The post may be old but the link is to the same section of Google's API documentation that your post is concerned with, namely http://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3 .  There you will find documentation for different languages including Java, Python, .NET, and HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best resource is: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ & https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference, this is the most accurate and up-to-date resource available at this time.

I realise this is not the answer you want, but it is the correct answer nonetheless.